# How to properly maintain the index in a JQuery Counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

So let's say I have five divs. I am trying to show the first 3 divs and then showing a new div and removing a div on a set interval.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="speaker">One</div>
<div class="speaker">Two</div>
<div class="speaker">Three</div>
<div class="speaker">Four</div>
<div class="speaker">Five</div>
```

The JS Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/mirzar/Sny3e/8/.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong in terms of not keeping the current index? Once it has show the Fifth speaker, I am trying to iterate back to go from "Three Four Five" to "Two Three Four" and then "One Two Three" and then re-starting from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your fiddle and tried to not modify as much as possible. I set a flag to check which direction we are going up or down. When we are going back down the index we check to see if were back at 0 again, if so we reset all of our index positions to their default.

When you are using the current index as the condition on each pass, what ends up happening is you get to a point where it teeters back and forth between passing and failing. Which is why it is better, to set a 'flag' variable to dictate which set of statements should be run.

```
var speakers = $(".speaker").length;
var currIndex = 0;
var endIndex = 0;
var reverseIndex = 0;
var up = true;

if (speakers > 3) {
   $(".speaker").hide();
   $('.speaker:lt(3)').show();
   var refreshId = setInterval(speaker_slides, 2000);
}

function speaker_slides() {

  if (up) {
    endIndex = currIndex + 3;
    $(".speaker").eq(currIndex).hide(500);
    $(".speaker").eq(endIndex).delay(500).show(500);
    currIndex++;
    $("#currIn").empty().append(currIndex);
    up = currIndex >= 2 ? false : true;
  } else {
    currIndex--;
    endIndex = currIndex;
    reverseIndex--;
    $(".speaker").eq(reverseIndex).hide(500);
    $(".speaker").eq(endIndex).delay(500).show(500);
    if(currIndex == 0) {
      up = true;
      endIndex = 0;
      reverseIndex = 0;
    }
  }

}
```

This can be cleaned up quite a bit but I think it's working as you were originally intending it to.

Hope it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjcYd/

Comment: Thanks. So much. Yours worked properly. I need modify a little bit so that the up variable wasn't set by a hard-coded number. Here's my fork http://jsfiddle.net/mirzar/Ezan5/1/

Answer (score 1):

I forked your jsfiddle and tried modifying in my way:

http://jsfiddle.net/dharmavir/74KQc/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slides = $(".speaker").length;
  $.each( $(".speaker"), function(index, node) {
    $(node).data("rank", index+1);
  });
  $(".speaker").hide();
  setInterval(slideRoller, 2000);
});

function slideRoller()
{
  rollSlides("container", "slides", "speaker", 1, 5, 3);
}

function rollSlides(containerDisplay, containerParent, elmSetClass, startIndex, endIndex, displayLimit)
{
  $("#"+containerDisplay).empty();
  $.each( $("."+elmSetClass), function() {
    var rank = $(this).data("rank");

    if( rank <= displayLimit )
    {
      $(this).clone().show().appendTo("#"+containerDisplay);
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).hide().appendTo("#"+containerParent);
    }
    if( rank <= startIndex )
    {
      rank = endIndex;
    }
    else 
    {
      rank = rank - 1;
    }
    $(this).data("rank", rank);
  });
}
```

Comment: Forked yours here - http://jsfiddle.net/mirzar/2Q3mN/. Loved your solution. Only downside is that it can't do Fades or Slide Up/Down since you show/hide the entire thing

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an answer but you might be interested in a more generalized, compact solution :

```
  var $speakers = $(".speaker");
  var dims = {
    length: $speakers.length,
    batch: 3
  };
  var i = 0; //currIndex
  var dir = 1; //direction
  var offset = {};

  if (dims.length > dims.batch) {
    $speakers.hide();
    $('.speaker:lt(' + dims.batch + ')').show();
    var refreshId = setInterval(speaker_slides, 2000);
  }

  function speaker_slides() {
    i = i + dir;
    $("#currIn").text(i);
    offset.h = (dir == 1) ? -1 : dims.batch;
    offset.s = (dir == 1) ? dims.batch - 1 : 0;
    $speakers.eq(i + offset.h).hide(500);
    $speakers.eq(i + offset.s).delay(500).show(500);
    dir = (i <= 0) ? 1 : (i >= dims.length - dims.batch) ? -1 : dir;
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sny3e/11/)**

All the constants are derived from `dims.length` and `dims.batch`.

For different behaviour, simply change `dims.batch` to 1, 2 or 4.